# How to calculate the time taken to load module in gwt?

Tags: gwt

I am using a custom gridview widget and large amount of data(say 1000 rows) assigned to it.I know that it will take more time.And I want to know how much time it exactly taking to load the grid.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Custom.css">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>CustomWidget</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mywidget/mywidget.nocache.js">
    function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="startTime()">
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
<div id="txt"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But not able display time..and its working when executing as single html page.

Comment: Ado you want to know the time taken to load the `nocache.js`? or do you want to know the time taken to populate the date in list grid.

Comment: thanks @Braj yes I want know time taken to load nocache.js and I am getting time(millisec) at which data row added to grid.but not able to get time taken to load module in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

Steps to follow:

- create a hidden div that have a information about current time before downloading `nocache.js`
- Once `nocache.js` is loaded it will call `EntryPoint#onModuleLoad()` method of your entry point class.
- Compare the time to get the time taken

HTML/JSP:

```
<body>
    <div id="timeinfo" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var today = new Date();

        document.getElementById("timeinfo").innerHTML = today.getTime();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="mywidget/mywidget.nocache.js"></script>
</body>
```

Entry point class:

```
public class MyWidget implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel timeinfo = RootPanel.get("timeinfo");

        long startTime = Long.valueOf(timeinfo.getElement().getInnerHTML());
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(new Date(startTime));
        System.out.println(new Date(endTime));
        System.out.println("Total time taken=" + (endTime - startTime) + " ms.");

        RootPanel.getBodyElement().removeChild(timeinfo.getElement());
        ...
    }
}
```

output:

```
    Tue Apr 22 16:55:49 IST 2014
    Tue Apr 22 16:56:03 IST 2014
    Total time taken=14479 ms.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another two ways along with @Braj  answer

**1.Using Speed Tracer you are able to get a better picture of where time is being spent in your application. This includes problems caused by:**

- Javascript parsing and execution
- Layout
- CSS style recalculation and selector matching
- DOM Event handling
- Network resource loading
- Timer fires
- XMLHttpRequest callbacks
- Painting

Fallow this link [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-tracer-by-google/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) and to Crome(click on free) ,works with Crome only

**2.You can edit, debug, and monitor CSS, HTML, and JavaScript live in any web page**
With this we can get how much time each function taken , how many times is called and % of total time

but its works with fire fox only.

Fallow this link [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads).Click on **Console** and enable **Profile** to see the performance of each function.

Sometimes you may get obfuscated function names.To avoid this `project>Google>GWT Compile>`Select output style as `Pretty`

Comment: If you have the answers already then why you are asking it here?

Comment: SORRY,not mean to offend you @Braj ..after two  days of searching I came up with new solutions....I thought it could help others.

Comment: I strongly agree with you. Its a very good answer than me. I'll definitely up vote it.

Comment: Please make some edit so that I can revert my down-vote.

Comment: I was more concern about to log the time taken by the application rather than just to know it. All of your above option just tell you about the time taken but you can't log it anywhere.

Comment: As per your comment in question itself your want know time taken to load `nocache.js` only.

Comment: Sorry but your peers is suggesting wrong. `onModuleLoad()` method is called when `nocahce.js` is loaded because it's called from `nocache.js` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Open console in your browser. Click on the Network tab. Reload the page. See how long it takes to load each resource.

Comment: Yes @Andrei Volgin...we can see how much time it's taken...but I would like to print that time instead of calculating manually....thank you..